# Enter terminal mode with bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tty

Is there a possibility to enter the terminal mode accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> with a bash command so that I can tell a script to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you intend to use a command in a script, you probably want to use something that doesn't need root privileges to be ran as 'chvt' or 'openvt' .

That's why you may prefer [`xdotool`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool]. After you have installed, you can use the following command to simulate this shortcut input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+F1
```

Answer (score 3):

Command for changing virtual terminals is named `chvt`. In gnome-terminal:

```
$ sudo chvt 1
```

Here is an exmplanation why do you need `sudo`: https://superuser.com/questions/69807/why-does-chvt-work-fine-as-a-regular-user-on-a-virtual-terminal-but-not-under-x

In a virtual terminals 1-6 root privileges aren't needed.

To run a command on another virtual terminal you can use `openvt`:

```
$ sudo openvt -s pwd
```

More examples and explanation here: http://www.ae.iitm.ac.in/pipermail/ilugc/2008-December/045004.html